# How to create a new user in read only file system?

Tags: linux

I'm trying to create a new user in Linux file system. The file system is read only. I'm not allowed to remount with read/write permission.

I tried overlayfs by mounting the read only partition to read/write partition using the below command

```
mount -t overlay overlay -o lowerdir=/etc,upperdir=/data/etc,workdir=/data/overlayfs_workdir  /etc
```

but I'm getting the following error when I tried to create a new user

```
root@a1:~# luseradd testuser

Error creating group `testuser': error creating `/etc/group-': Text file busy
```

Any thoughts on how to fix this error?

Comment: What if you try manually adding a user, i.e. echo a line onto the end of the passwd/shadow/group files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that overlay file system doesn't support renaming files.

There is a CONFIG_OVERLAY_FS_REDIRECT_DIR kernel configuration which enables this feature and available for kernel version above 4.10, but our Linux kernel version is 3.9; So this is not an option for us.

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt

Another approach is to change the default path in /etc/libuser.conf of shadow and user files to a read/write directory instead of /etc and copy the files there.

Thus all the changes and renaming are done in read/write directory and this path is given as upper directory to mount overlay command.

```
mount -t overlay overlay -o lowerdir=/etc,upperdir=/data/etc,workdir=/data/overlayfs_workdir  /etc
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to write I don't think you can create a user.

However, If you want a temporary access to the system you can use the partition /dev/shm like that **mount -o remount,size=8G /dev/shm**

It will allow you to write on the ram and use it as a normal partition

more info at: : https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/what-is-devshm-and-its-practical-usage.html